Display Product Category Description in WooCommerce between pagination and products
I'm currently facing an issue with my WooCommerce store and would appreciate any insights or solutions you might have.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve: I want to display the product category description on my category pages, specifically below the pagination and above the product listings. I've been following various tutorials, but I haven’t had any success so far.
Here’s what I’ve done:
I located the archive-product.php file in my theme and made modifications to include the category description.
I’ve used the following code in my archive-product.php file:
if ( is_product_category() ) : ?>
    <div class="category-description">
        <?php 
        echo term_description(); // Display the product category description 
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; 

What I’ve Observed:
I added a debug message to confirm that the archive-product.php template is loading, but I haven’t seen any output confirming this.
I verified that I’m on the correct product category page, but the description still does not appear.
My Environment:
I’m using the Active7 theme (child theme of The7).
Everything mentioned above

First, as some themes make their own customizations, overriding WooCommerce templates, you need to look inside your main theme for a folder called "woocommerce". Also, themes can manipulate things by removing some original sections via hooks, that are replaced by their own (this is more complicated to find out inside the theme files).


Since you’re using a child theme of “The7”, WooCommerce templates
might be overridden by the parent theme. First, ensure that
archive-product.php is the correct file that WooCommerce is using.
Check if the parent theme or child theme includes a file like
taxonomy-product_cat.php or content-product_cat.php.

You can try this function
// Display category description below pagination and above product listings
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'display_category_description', 5 );

function display_category_description() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $term_description = term_description();
        if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) {
            echo '<div class="category-description">' . $term_description . '</div>';
        }
    }
}


taxonomy-product_cat.php was under woocommerce plugin but code within that file code is if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
I have even instaled different plugins related to adding secondary description or description but no description showing , here is website link if you can help to fix it https://www.cottonfieldpk.com/product-category/cotton-bags/
